# ¿Cómo activo las extensiones Firebird e Interbase en PHP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Tengo problemas para activar las extensiones de Firebird e Interbase que necesito para realizar unas migraciones. Cuando intento ejecutar el comando php migrate me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando en internet encontré que debía colocar la dll: `fbclient.dll` en System32, efectivamente lo hice y por si acaso, también lo coloque en SysWOW.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Xampp así que también verifique la ruta

```
C:\xampp\php y C:\xampp\apache en ambos lugares coloque el archivo fbclient.dll.
```

También descargue las dll de 32 bits `php_pdo_firebird` y `php_interbase` en una página y sustituí los que tenía en la ruta 
`C:\xampp\php\ext`

No sé que más hacer pues me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje de error y creo que probé todo lo que encontré en internet.

Comment: que version de PHP estas utilizando?

Comment: La versión de PHP es 7.2.29

Comment: Yo pienso que estas utilizando las dll para 64bits, descarga las dll para 32bits desde este [enlace oficial](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2-nts-VC15-x86) luego sustituyelas en tu entorno y me comentas

Comment: Descargué las dll y las coloqué en System32, SysWOW, C:\xampp\php y C:\xampp\php\ext pero me sigue mostrando exactamente el mismo mensaje de error.

Comment: Aca tienes la documentacion de [Firebird/InterBase](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.ibase.php) en español, revisa los requerimientos de instalacion y sigue el paso a paso de la instalacion, seguramente mirando esta informacion das con tu problema. Suerte